# Error "Permission denied" after execute npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

After executing `npm install`, occurs following error:

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /var/www/html/node_modules/core-js
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! sh: 1: node: Permission denied
```

I'm executing command as a root on Docker. I tried to set `npm config set user 0` and `npm config set unsafe-perm true` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

I changed files ownership to root, and after that everything work.
`chown -R root:root .`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when you install packages using `sudo`. That's why you shouldn't install any package using `sudo` keyword.

The solution: Delete `node_modules` folder. If it says that you don't have permission then delete it directly from `folder` (not from IDE) or through the terminal.

After that `install your packages` again. This time only `npm i` without `sudo`.

Comment: I'm in docker container, so how can I run command not as root?